# Function for Size of datatypes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any SQL function / method to find out the number of bytes used to represent each data type?
I understand that there are [lists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) available. 
However, is there a method to find out using MySQL ?

Edit: Is it possible in sqlplus ?

Comment: Probably not, but you can write your own functions.

Comment: There's no such function, nor could one be accurate seeing we can use variable length data types. However, there exists [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) which you can query to obtain exact information on a column of a table. I've no idea whether you need a reference function for data type lenght or you need to inspect an existing table column, but whatever the case is - I don't think such a function is even useful.